# {packages} and {package-writing} tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

According to the [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) tag wiki:

> This tag marks questions which are
>   about packages in general, for
>   instance about installing, using or
>   writing packages.

We also have 6 questions tagged with [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing), none of which is tagged [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages).

Is the [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing) tag redundant and should be merged into [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages)? Or should we remove the ”writing”-part from [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages)? Or should [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing) be a tag that can be applied in addition to [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages)?

Further, current usage seems to be tag requests for a package that does something specific with [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages). Should there be a separate tag for these kinds of question? (We had a [package-hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-hint) tag, but I was only used by one question. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing) should be preserved because creation and writing is very different to usage. Package writers should be able to find specific questions instead of looking them up among a huge amount of choosing and using questions.

As the general tag [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) is mostly used for requests regarding recommendations of packages, I would not introduce another tag for that. Renaming or a synonym would be possible. But I don't see a need for that action. For specific questions there might be tags created, such as [package-options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-options) or [package-installing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-installing) if meaningful. It's good to differentiate. I just don't see the need to retag 50 [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) questions to [package-hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-hint).

I would edit the [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) wiki to clarify that for questions about writing the other tag should be chosen.